# AppFabric replacement with Redis

Tags: redis, appfabric

With AppFabric now coming to EOL we are considering the viability of using Redis as the caching solution. One concern we have is that we are currently storing large objects (approx 40M) in AppFabric. Does anyone have any experience of storing objects of this size and any challenges this may pose ? Plus any general view on the move from AppFabric to Redis would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to check out the [AppFabric to Memurai migration article](https://www.memurai.com/blog/appfabric-caching-migration-guide). Using Memurai Developer you can test and confirm that the ~40 MB objects are properly handled.